# Updating part of a setData state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, fetch-api

I have a web app where I need to fetch some data now and then. I handle the states via `zustand` with the following:

```
import { create } from "zustand";

type State = {
    data: any;
    setData: (data: any) => void;,
};

const returnObjects = {
    df: [],
    df_other: [],
};

const myData = create<State>((set) => ({
    data: returnObjects,
    setData: (data) => set((state) => ({ ...state, data: { ...state.data, ...data }})),
}));

export default myData ;
```

I then do a fetch that looks something like:

```
const {isLoading, isError, isFetching} = useQuery(
        ["fetch_my_data"],
        () => fetchData("fetch_my_data", { data1: my_data1, data2: my_data2}),
        {
            retry: false,
            onSuccess: (newData) => {
                setData({ df_other: newData});
            }
        }
    );
```

So basically I am giving my backend some data, and then it does something and returns it to me. I know that what I get back (`newData`) is correct. My problems arise when replacing/updating the `data` via `setData`. Doing this, `df_other` now have a nested name. So instead of just `data` having `df_other` and then the data, it now has `df_other` which then have `df_other` and then the data. And I'm not really sure how I remove this "nesting" problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this code helps you:

```
setData: (data) =>
  set((state) => ({ ...state, data: { ...state.data, ...data } }));
```

And then:

```
setData({ df_other: newData.df_other });
```

Comment: Isn't that exactly what I have written?

Comment: Sorry, I was confused. Can you use setData({ df_other: newData.df_other });?

Comment: That seemed to do it.